# find and parse values from string

Tags: c#

I have a string that I am trying to parse the values from. It is in this format `"43,56,12,ddl=345"`.

I am trying to store the ddl value (`345`) in a separate variable, then the other numbers in a list.

```
List<int> nums = new List<int>();
int? ddlValue;
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: use [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) to split on comma, then split the last element in array on `=` .....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I mean the simplest way is a split and replace.

```
  string values = "43,56,12,ddl=345";

        string[] values1 = values.Split(',');

        foreach (var x in values1)
        {
            list.Add(x);
        } 

  string myvalue = values.Split(',')[3];
  myvalue = myvalue.Replace("ddl=","");
```

this assumes your going to be getting the same format every time. Maybe more information?

EDIT-

If you will not always have 3 numbers then the ddl= then string myvalue = values.Split(',')[3]; will not work. Theres a few easy ways around it like

```
    string myvalue = values.Split(',')[values1.Count() - 1]
```

Comment: the numbers in the front will change, it could be 23 or they could be 23,34,65,34,34 I put the ddl= to tell me what control that specific number was coming from.

Comment: I'm not sure that the last line will do what you want it to do... And in fact the second line throws an error when run (you seem to be splitting into an array but then assigning to a string and the split method is not valid...

Comment: this really isn't ideal

Comment: This is still a pretty poor answer. lowNums is unnecessary, list isn't declared, myvalue is a string of value "ddl=345345" which is useful to nobody and it doesn't deal with a variable number of numbers at the front as jpavlov stated as a requirement in his first comment. I am failing to understand how this answer was accepted. Oh, and case issues with `Add` and `Replace`.

Comment: The guys wants an easy simple solution he can understand. This gives it to him. 
@Chris I fail to see where he stated a variable number of numbers in the question. Once I learned that I fixed it. Idunno why your mad bro.

Comment: Calvin, I will probably refactor this in a couple of years when my skills become more solid, but for right now, it makes sense to me. Seems like Chris is a poor sport.

Comment: I'm not mad. I'm offering constructive criticism. Your code isn't a solution since it doesn't compile and didn't give the results needed in one case (ddl). It doesn't cope with a variable number of input numbers because you are hardcoding index 3 in getting the `ddl=` string. The lowNums is still pointless because it just doesn't do anything but complicate things.

Comment: @jpavlov: Think that if you will. I just think given you had several answers that do what you wanted cleanly and with code that compiles I am struggling to understand why you accepted an answer that didn't compile and didn't give you the results you want. It has now been improved such that it does give the right results and that is exactly why I was offering up those criticisms. It reflects badly on the site if an accepted answer doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @jpavlov I know you will. There are far easier ways to do this but you asked for the simplest solution. When I first started, either freeaslnBeer or daves answers are way better, but there is no way I would have easily looked at it and said oh I see what it does.

Comment: @CalvinSmith: Incomplete is how I would describe it rather than wrong. The OP wanted a `List<int>` with the numbers in. Your `list` variable is a list of strings that includes `ddl=345` as the last value. A complete answer would leave me with a `List<int>` and a `int?` at the end with the right information in.

Comment: Chris's points are extremely valid.  It's not 'wrong', but it is not well written and won't withstand very minor and likely changes in input.

Comment: @CalvinSmith: I was actually just about to go tidy up some of my earlier comments that have been obsoleted by your efforts. And its not a comment war, its me trying to help you make your answer better and for some reason you don't want to which I don't quite understand.

Comment: I don't understand the criticism. I understand that all the points are valid, most people are not idiots. Howvever I think that this is pointless. He needed a point in the right direction, thats all my code was meant to provide. Im not in the habit of taking a long time to edit the code to meet the exact specifications of the poster. He understands what the code I provided does, and is able to modify it to meet his exact needs. Is that not the point of SO? FreeAslnBeer's code is perfect and more correct, but the OP would be right back here asking how to edit it.

Comment: @CalvinSmith: That's a valid point about giving him a pointer but I am not sure I would agree that other answers would leave him unable to edit it but yours would. I'll leave off any other constructive criticism since it is clearly not wanted but I am still intrigued though by what your intent was with `lowNums`?

Comment: @Chris I was writing an answer similar to Bear's, saw that the OP just wanted a simple answer, and never went back to change my code. I don't mind construction criticism at all, but saying that my add and replace methods are not capitalized is not constructive criticism.

Answer (score 5):

You could try parsing the string for ints, and then have special checks for any other values you want to store.

```
var sNums = "43,56,12,ddl=345";

List<int> nums = new List<int>();
int? ddlValue;

foreach (var t in sNums.Split(',')) {
    int u;
    if (int.TryParse(t, out u)) {
        nums.Add(u);
    } else {
        ddlValue = t.Split("=")[1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
var sNums = "43,56,12,ddl=345".Split(',');

var ddl = int.Parse(sNums.First(s => s.Contains("ddl")).Replace("ddl=", ""));
var numbers = sNums.Where(s => !s.Contains("ddl")).Select(int.Parse);
```

*note - this will be slightly less efficient that doing it in a single loop - but more readable IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
List<int> nums=new List<int>();
int intVariable = 0;
string s = "43,56,12,ddl=345";
string[] split=s.Split(',');
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d+$");
foreach(var element in split)
  if(regex.IsMatch(element))
      nums.Add(Convert.ToInt32(element));
  else
  {
       intVariable = element.Split("=")[1];
  }
```

Comment: Did you mean `foreach (var element in split)`?